# Matrix representation of linear transformation over the space of polynomials - deducing onto and one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Let $\mathcal P_1=\{bx+c: b,\in\mathbb R\}\deg p=1$ define $T: \mathcal P_1\to \mathcal P_1$ by $T(bx+c):=(2b+c)x-c$
>
> 1. How do you get the elements of  $\mathcal P_1$ to a vector $R^2$ and then write T as a 2x2 matrix M.

What I just found on a scratch is I wrote (bx+c)=> Matrix [b,c]=[2b+c,-c]=> [2b,c,0,-c]

Would the 2x2 matrix of M just be [2,1,0,-1]?

> 2. Explain why T is a one-to-one and onto. (You may use the matrix M, but make sure I know you understand the meaning of one-to-one and onto)

For this question I will need to know if I did Number 1 correct.

This was a question I got stuck on to a test that I submitted 2 weeks ago, but my professor hasn't gotten back to my question about the answer and the test is locked down so I am not able to provide what I got.

If anyone can help and explain it and what answer you got that would be tremendous help to knowing how I did on this part.

Comment: Since the test is already locked down, why not wait until you get it back and ask your professor? As it stands now, it looks like you are asking us to do a problem for you. To clarify and help us help you, perhaps you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: It's because my professor said he would have it too us last week and he hasn't responded too any of my emails so this is my last option for any sort of clarification.

Comment: But I will edit this post to ask a more specific question

Comment: @Displayer could you tell us roughly where you got stuck and what you wrote for an answer, then?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I basically put what Ironx just wrote except I had my matrix flipped

Answer (score 1):

One answer is as follows:

Let $\mathcal B$ denote the standard basis $\mathcal B = \{1,x\}$ of $\mathcal P_1$.  Then for a polynomial $p(x) = a + bx$, the [coordinate vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) of $p$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is given by
$$
[p]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{a\\b} =: (a,b).
$$
So in other words, we write the polynomial $a + bx$ as the vector $(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$.

One way to find the matrix of a transformation relative to a choice of basis is to see what happens to each basis element.  For instance, to find the second column of the transformation, plug $x$ (the second element of $\mathcal B$) to find that
$$
T(x) = T(1 \cdot x + 0) = (2(1) + 0)x - (0) = 0 \cdot 1 + 2\cdot x.
$$
The second column of the matrix of $T$ relative to $\mathcal B$ is the coordinate vector of $T(x)$, which is $(0,2)$.  So the matrix of $T$ has the form
$$
M = [T]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{?&0\\?&2}.
$$
Relative to the basis I have chosen, the matrix is given by $M = \pmatrix{-1&0\\1&2}$. Relative to the basis $\mathcal B' = \{x,1\}$, we would end up with the matrix $M = \pmatrix{2&1\\0&-1}$. Both of these answers are correct.

---

We could do part 2 without using the matrix as follows:
$T$ is one to one if the only solution to $T(p(x)) = 0$ is $p(x) = 0x + 0 = 0$. We note that if $p(x) = bx + c$, then 
$$
T(p) = 0 \implies (2b + c)x - c = 0 \implies \begin{cases}
2b + c = 0\\
-c = 0
\end{cases} 
$$
Solving this system of equations from the bottom up tells us that $c = 0$ and $b = 0$, so that we must have $p(x) = 0$.  So, $T$ is one to one.

$T$ is onto if the equation $T(p(x)) = q(x)$ has a solution for every $q$.  Writing out $T(p(x)) = q(x)$ where $p(x) = bx + c$ and $q(x) = mx + k$ gives us the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
2b + c = m\\
-c = k.
\end{cases} 
$$
It suffices to note that this system of equations has a solution for any $m$ and $k$.

Comment: Awesome thank you, That looks pretty close to what I put so I feel so much better. Also At the very top is the "T is onto if the" suppose to be One-to-one?

Comment: @Displayer123 Yes, that's right; silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the basis $\beta = \{1, x \}$ for $\mathcal{P}_1$.

Then, the representation of $p = a + bx$ with respect to the basis is called $[p]_\beta$ $$[p]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}$$

So in the $\beta$ coordinates, the action of $T(bx + c) = (2b + c)x - c $ translates to: $$T : \begin{bmatrix}
c\\
b
\end{bmatrix} \mapsto \begin{bmatrix}
-c\\
2b + c
\end{bmatrix} $$

The associated matrix $[T]_\beta$ is $$[T]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} $$

because $$\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
c\\
b 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
-c \\
2b + c 
\end{bmatrix}$$

If $V, W$ are equal dimensional vector spaces and $T : V \to W$ is a linear transformation, then being onto and one-to-one are equivalent.

Hence, the transformation $T : \mathcal{P}_1 \to \mathcal{P}_1$ is **both** one-to-one and onto if the associated matrix $[T]_\beta$ is

- invertible
- has nonzero determinant
- has null space $ = \{0 \}$

Checking any one condition in the above list would suffice.